# How to make flexbox divs full width

Tags: html, css, width, flexbox

What I'm trying to do is make each one of those 'divs' in the 'aside' tag to be full-width using flexbox.

The width of the sidebar is 25% however the divs don't fill in the space on the left & right side. I can add padding to each side but it get's a bit messy and ruins the `align-items: center`

If you run the below at full screen, you'll see what I mean.

```css
aside {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 25%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
aside div {
  padding: 89.9px;
}
.test1 {
  background-color: gray;
}
.test2 {
  background-color: red;
}
.test3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.test4 {
  background-color: green;
}
.test5 {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
</head>

<body>

  <aside>
    <div class="test1">234324</div>
    <div class="test2">232</div>
    <div class="test3">3234324234</div>
    <div class="test4">2344</div>
    <div class="test5">234234234233245</div>
  </aside>

</body>

</html>
```

I've achieved it below (see image) without using flexbox but I'd really like to make it work with flexbox.

[Without flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZATXL.png)

Comment: Have you tried adding `width: 100%;` to the CSS of your `aside div` selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove `"align-items:center;"` it will force the divs to take up the whole space within the column.

If you decide you want space in between or whatever, or you need to have them aligned, use can use `justify-content:center;` which will still have them take up the whole div.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Will. Would I than just center the text inside using padding?

Comment: You can use text-align:center; to center the text. Add that to the flex-container(aside)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for that.